# Cutting a XNA model in half by removing vertices and indices

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, indices, vertices

I am attempting to cut a loaded 3D model in half using MonoGame (which is extremely similar XNA). I do not need to do this in real time so performance is not a huge issue.

I get my vertices and indices using the `ModelMeshPart` as such.

```
Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[part.NumVertices];
part.VertexBuffer.GetData<Vector3>(vertices);

short[] indices = new short[part.PrimitiveCount * 3];
part.IndexBuffer.GetData<short>(indices);
```

and then set them using

```
part.IndexBuffer.SetData<Vector3>(vertices);
part.VertexBuffer.SetData<short>(indices);
```

Prior to that though I take those arrays and try to empty out all vertices (and indices that refer to them) that are positioned behind the center Z location of the model as such.

```
float centerZ = modelMesh.BoundingSphere.Center.Z;

for (int i = 0; i < indices.Length; i += 3)
{
    short index0 = indices[i];
    short index1 = indices[i + 1];
    short index2 = indices[i + 2];

    Vector3 vert0 = vertices[index0];
    Vector3 vert1 = vertices[index1];
    Vector3 vert2 = vertices[index2];

    if (vert0.Z > centerZ && vert1.Z > centerZ && vert2.Z > centerZ)
    {
        vert0 = Vector3.Zero;
        vert1 = Vector3.Zero;
        vert2 = Vector3.Zero;
        indices[i] = short.MinValue;
        indices[i + 1] = short.MinValue;
        indices[i + 2] = short.MinValue;                
    }
}
```

but in the end I get something that looks like this rather than a model cut in half. I am completely new to games programming and my comprehension of vertices and indices is still extremely poor. Obviously I am missing something really fundamental, any help would be sincerely appreciated.

[image]

Comment: If you don't need to do it in realtime, could you do it in your 3D model editor of choice? Most tools have a slice function that could regenerate the mesh for you. Would be much easier.  Wishing you well

Answer (score 0):

short.MinValue is -32767 since short is signed, so you shouldn't be using that, since the indice value for the vertice can't be negative. You should use = 0 or ushort.MinValue. Also keep in mind that this method will not cut the model in half perfectly, triangles perpendicular to the center will still remain.

You can try something like this:

```
if (vert0.Z <= centerZ || vert1.Z <= centerZ || vert2.Z <= centerZ)
{
    if (vert0.Z > centerZ) vert0.Z = centerZ;
    if (vert1.Z > centerZ) vert1.Z = centerZ;
    if (vert2.Z > centerZ) vert2.Z = centerZ;           
}
else
{
    indices[i] = 0;
    indices[i + 1] = 0;
    indices[i + 2] = 0; 
}
```

**Edit:**
also this part looks wrong:

```
part.IndexBuffer.SetData<short>(vertices);
part.VertexBuffer.SetData<Vector3>(indices);
```

you should pass vertices to the VertexBuffer and indices to the IndexBuffer. And you should probably use ushort on indices, since theres no reason a indice would be negative.